# Grouping Data Based on Reference Table

Tags: mysql, group-by

Data for **province** table:

```
idProv  Province
1       JT
2       JB
3       BT
```

Data for **City** table:

```
idCity  IdProv  City
  1     1       BL  
  2     1       ML  
  3     1       MD  
  4     2       CB  
  5     2       TM  
  6     3       YK  
  7     3       SM
```

Data for **data** table:

```
idData  idCity  population  data1   data2
1       1       100         200     200
2       2       100         200     300
3       3       50          100     150
4       4       20          10      20
5       5       20          20      40
6       6       50          200     400
7       7       50          100     200
```

I want to group data from data table for each province.

The output should be:

```
Province    population  data1   data2
JT          250         500     750
JB          40          30      60
BT          100         300     600
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f12596)

Comment: Hi and welcome. In Stack Overflow we expect you to have a go at it yourself first, and then we will help you. When I look - that fiddle has nothing in it. What have you tried to get this working (even f it doesn't work)? and what were the problems you encountered? (don't reply in comments, edit your answer and add your code).

Comment: Hi Taryn, Im just learning mysql so i try everything but can not get the result so i decide not to put my mysql query on to my question ..

Comment: I understand, but that's not how Stack Overflow works - we want to see it - even if it's wrong - because then we can see that A) you've at least had a go at it yourself (we're more likely to help somebody that has had a go themselves than somebody who's just asking us to do it all for them) B) a bit more understanding of what you're trying to do (sometimes seeing how you tried it shows us what you're trying to do, and sometimes it shows us where the error in your thinking is that we can let you know and you can then understand better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the 3 tables using `INNER JOIN` and get the `SUM` of each columns such as  `population`,`data1`, and `data2`. Then I applied the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` to get your desired result. See my query and demo below:

```
SELECT 
      Province, 
      SUM(population) AS Population, 
      SUM(data1) AS Data1, 
      SUM(data2) AS Data2
FROM data A 
INNER JOIN City B ON A.idCity=B.idCity
INNER JOIN Province C ON B.Idprov=C.Idprov
GROUP BY Province
ORDER BY Province DESC
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f12596/8/0)**